# Swift: Drag and Drop delegate - unable to drag out text view when dropped into another text view

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop

I'm currently creating an amazing race type of mobile app where players will play different games based on their location. One of the games they have to play would be a typical drag and drop game. I'm currently able to perform the drag to drop for 2 textviews. However:

- I'm unable to drag out the previous dropped item so that I can put it back to its initial spot and also to drag other items to the dropped location
- Each dropped location can only have 1 item
- I should be able to get the match the content of dragged item to dropped item so that I know it is the correct option in order to tabulate the score
- How do I scale it for multiple UITextViews to drag and to drop

I've created a sample to test it out, with 2 UITextView - 1 for drag and 1 for drop. Drag works but I'm not too sure how to drag it out after I've dropped it in.

With the following view controller:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIDragInteractionDelegate, UIDropInteractionDelegate{
  @IBOutlet weak var dragTextView: UITextView!
  @IBOutlet weak var dropTextView: UITextView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dragTextView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    dropTextView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    dropTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    dropTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

    let dragTextInteraction = UIDragInteraction(delegate: self)
    let dropTextInteraction = UIDropInteraction(delegate: self)

    dragTextInteraction.isEnabled = true

    dragTextView.addInteraction(dragTextInteraction)
    dropTextView.addInteraction(dropTextInteraction)

  }

  func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
    return session.hasItemsConforming(toTypeIdentifiers: [kUTTypePlainText as String])
  }

  func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession) -> UIDropProposal {
    let location = session.location(in: self.view)
    let dropOperation: UIDropOperation?

    if session.canLoadObjects(ofClass: String.self) {

      if dropTextView.frame.contains(location) {
        dropOperation = .copy
      } else {
        dropOperation = .cancel
      }
    } else {
      dropOperation = .cancel
    }

    return UIDropProposal(operation: dropOperation!)
  }

  func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {
    if session.canLoadObjects(ofClass: String.self) {

      session.loadObjects(ofClass: String.self) { (items) in
        let values = items as [String]
        self.dropTextView.text = values.last

      }
    }
  }

  func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession) -> [UIDragItem] {

    if let textView = interaction.view as? UITextView {
      let textToDrag = textView.text
      let provider = NSItemProvider(object: textToDrag! as NSString)
      let item = UIDragItem(itemProvider: provider)
      return [item]
    }

    return []
  }
}
```

Have been troubled over this. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)